# How to keep sync between Canvas and UV Editor

Tags: uv-image-editor

When switching between objects the mesh from the picked object will change in the UV Editor only if I go to Edit Mode, but the Canvas Image remains the same as the last object edited.  Node Editor will update by itself.  If I go to Texture Paint the correct image is shown overlaid on the object in 3D View with Material View turned on but it does not change in the UV Editor or Canvas Image selection.  Going to Solid View shows the old image overlaid in the 3D View.  In order to get the correct Image shown everywhere I have to go to Texture Paint to manually change to it.

How can I get everything to sync automatically with an object when it is picked?

[image]

[PACKED BLEND FILE](https://we.tl/t-gLhFUUJjsE)

Comment: If I understand correctly you ask why image shown in UV image editor remans the same even if another object in 3d viewport with another image texture was selected. In short this is a feature which was introduced in around 2.6x versions. Somehow related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/automatic-update-of-the-image-in-the-uv-image-editor. In 2.8 after entering Edit mode image will be changed if there's another one selected in material

Comment: I was asking because until a few days ago I did not notice the UV Texture and Image falling out of sync whenever I changed to a different object.  Now I have to check five places every time I go to another object to verify that the mesh and artwork files are properly aligned before I dare make any changes.

Comment: Almost a year passed, did you solve it?  This is irritating.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (in Blender 2.8) is to click the unpin button in *UV Editor*. Then you will get the assigned texture whenever you select an object and turn it to *Edit Mode*.

[image: Toolbar of UV Editor]